# get values from multiple form tags action to single jsp and insert them to sql database

Tags: jsp

I'm having a readymade template wherein there are 3 fields as dropdownlists:technology,Subtechnology and Skills.I need to add a subtechnology based upon the technology selected from dropdownlist and it has to get inserted in the database as well. This is done in jsp. I'm unable to do this as the 3 fields are created in separate form tags having separate action. may I know how to get the value of technology being selected and user input subtechnology via jsp and pass the same to insert into the sql database where subtechnology has technology id as foreign key.

please reply for this as I'm stuck in this part for my project

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this -

1> You can save the values from first 2 form tags to session variables. On submitting values from third form, you should get values from previous 2 session variables and current request variable and send all the values to database call (inserting the data)

2> You can make 3 input within same form tag and then you can use ajax for changing list of subtechnology on basis of technology and submit them all for the insert call to database.

May these help you.